# how to convert unicode entities to unicode text c#

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I have read some text from facebook using graph api and it return me message in form of unicode like this

\u092e\u094b\u0939\u093e\u0932\u0940 \u092e\u0947\u0902

so i want to convert this to text in c#.

like this online app is doing:
http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx):

```
Regex.Unescape("\u092e\u094b\u0939\u093e\u0932\u0940 \u092e\u0947\u0902")
```

Results in:

```
मोहाली में
```